# SQL query to get average per group in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, intersect

I have two tables: students and results.

For students, the fields are `student_id, name, grade`
For results, the fields are `student_id, score`

grade is like pre-school, one, two, three.... Like in a school.

As you see, `student_id` is in both tables.

I want a SQL query that returns average score per grade, like

```
Pre-School => 50 
Kindergarten => 26
```

etc.

I tried group by with left joins but nothing works.

The query I've been working on is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    cat.grade, 
    dog.score 
FROM (SELECT * FROM students GROUP BY grade) AS cat, results AS dog 
GROUP BY cat.grade
```

But this just gives me one result per grade, so `AVG()` does not give the right answer here.

Comment: would you like to get avarege score per grade for each student or for all student?

Comment: `SELECT AVG(score) FROM a JOIN b GROUP BY grade`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as joining the two table together, grouping on grade and selecting the average of all the scores.

```
SELECT grade, 
       Avg(score) 
FROM   students 
       JOIN results using (student_id) 
GROUP  BY grade
```

Comment: No problem, welcome to StackOverflow. Remember to up vote any answers you think is correct and accept the answer that best answers your question.

Comment: Thank you very much. I accepted your answer. I cannot upvote as I don't have less than 15 reputation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, avg(salary) avg_salary from Employee join results group by id order by avg(salary) desc;

  ID                 AVG_SALARY
 ---- ------------------------
 07                    7897.78
 02                    6661.78
 03                    6544.78
 06                    4322.78
 04                    2344.78
 05                    2334.78
 01                    1234.56
 08                    1232.78
```